# Qt Communication betwen threads, app design

Tags: qt

I'm working on an app which does some TCP communication, uses a database and has a GUI (pretty common). While experimenting with a database across the internet I've noticed slow responses of the GUI, which motivated using threads to handle the back end. I'm playing with this now and considering a full app re-design to adequately tackle the issue. So I'm imagining to separate GUI (a class derived from QMainWindow) and back end stuff (a domain class, derived from QObject). This domain class looks like (I say so because I'm clearly not an authority on patterns - always learning) a facade pattern. The idea is to construct both objects in the main function and then pass a pointer of DomainClass to MainWindow, i.e. MainWindow(DomainClass *domain).

Then comes the very point of this question. I'm imaging to construct many (not so much actually) objects in the Domain an make them communicate via signal/slots mechanics. Like the following:

```
QThread* threadDB = new QThread;
m_database = new Database;
m_database->moveToThread(threadDB);
threadDB->start();

QThread* threadTM = new QThread;
m_tm = new TM;
connect(m_database, &Database::dbConnected, m_tm, &TM::onDbConnected);
m_tm->moveToThread(threadTM);
connect(threadTM, &QThread::started, m_tm, &TM::init);
threadTM->start();
```

But I'm getting the following:

```
QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'QSqlDatabase'
(Make sure 'QSqlDatabase' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)
```

I've noted that it works fine if I leave m_tm out of the thread. Like the following:

```
QThread* threadDB = new QThread;
m_database = new Database;
m_database->moveToThread(threadDB);
threadDB->start();

m_tm = new TM;
connect(m_database, &Database::dbConnected, m_tm, &TM::onDbConnected);
```

Is this design reasonable? Which alternatives might be considered?

Comment: care to show `Database::dbConnected` declaration?

Comment: signals:
    void dbConnected(const QSqlDatabase &db);

Comment: In the end I found the Mandelbrot Example very usefull , http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcore-threads-mandelbrot-example.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues. First, the runtime error tells you exactly what's wrong. You're trying to pass a database instance by value. Pass it by a pointer instead. The Qt metatype system knows how to handle such pointers.

```
class Database {
  QSqlDatabase m_db;
  ...
public:
  Q_SIGNAL void dbConnected(QSqlDatabase*);
  ...
};
```

Secondly, you can only use a `QSqlDatabase` instance from the thread it was created in ([doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-modules.html#threads-and-the-sql-module)). So there's no point to passing it to an object living in a different thread. You should put `TM` in the same thread as that of the `Database` object, or you should have the `Database` object further encapsulate the database, exposing only a signal-slot interface that can then be used from any thread by using thread-safe queued calls.

Finally, you shouldn't use a "one thread per object" pattern. You must be able to give a reason, supported by measurements, that it is useful/helpful. A proliferation of threads is a bad thing - you should never have more than you have cores.

Comment: "You're trying to pass a database instance by value" actually I was passing it by reference (see my comment on the question). Anyway, doesn't matter. Pass it by a pointer instead solves the issue. Should I make `onDbConnected(QSqlDatabase * const db)`, in the slot side? Should I make `void dbConnected(QSqlDatabase * db) const`, in the signal side?

Comment: Contrary to the previous comment I've made, now I have an argument in favor of the reference style, instead of the pointer style. The runtime error was thrown because the connection was made between different threads (this is the important thing, so I see the error as a kind of confirmation I'm going in the right direction - using pointer style we loose this kind of confirmation), just have to make QMetaType know about that using `qRegisterMetaType<QSqlDatabase>("QSqlDatabase");`

Comment: @KcFnMi "I was passing it by reference" That is not possible between threads, when a queued connection is used. Queued connections require an arbitrary number of copies of the objects to be made, and you are effectively passing by value to each and every slot thus connected.

Comment: @KcFnMi In any case, I've already said that you **cannot do that**. There is a very good reason why this is not supposed to work - if you need to pass a `QSqlDatabase` through a signal-slot connection, your design is most likely broken. And in this case, it very much is so.

Answer (score 0):

I'm making this an answer to have more room, but it might be tough as a comment considering @Kuba Ober answer.

To solve the second issue (pointed by @Kuba Ober) may I move DomainClass entirely to another thread? Coding the following on the constructor:

```
QThread* thread = new QThread;
this->moveToThread(thread);
connect(thread, &QThread::started, this, &DomainClass::init);
thread->start();
```

and coding the following on init():

```
m_database = new Database;
m_tm = new TM;
connect(m_database, &Database::dbConnected, m_tm, &TM::onDbConnecte
```

Comment: Sure. And remember that the `started` to `init` idiom is entirely optional. If the object will *always* initialize itself as soon as you get it to its thread, you might as well not bother with that idiom. Recall that `QObject` are self-bootstrapping: they don't need anyone to send them any signals to get them going. In the `DomainClass`'s constructor, start a zero-timeout timer, and do the initialization work once that timer fires. That's the `QObject` bootstrap idiom.

Comment: `this->moveToThread` is a horrible anti-pattern. You're artificially limiting what the owner of that instance can do with it. Only its owner - by necessity, outside of the class's implementation - can move it to another thread. Perhaps the owner will be moved to another thread with your class, for example - such moves, if there's a parent-child relationship between objects, must be done atomically.

Answer (score 0):

In respect to @Kuba Ober comments...

Moved thread management job to domain's owner, so it does:

```
QThread *thread = new QThread;
domain->moveToThread(thread);
thread->start();
```

Changed Domain's constructor to do:

```
QTimer::singleShot(0, this, SLOT(init()));
```

Works pretty nice :)