# Avoid having to qRegisterMetaType (pointer vs reference), concern about const

Tags: qt

Given the signal:

```
void dbConnected(const QSqlDatabase &db);
```

I learned (from [Qt Communication betwen threads, app design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32137149/qt-communication-betwen-threads-app-design)) how to avoid having to use

```
qRegisterMetaType<QSqlDatabase>("QSqlDatabase");
```

Just changing the signal to this form:

```
void dbConnected(QSqlDatabase *db);
```

And, in the slot side I'll use something like this:

```
void onDBConnected(QSqlDatabase * const db);
```

I'm concerned with the usage of db (as in the beginning I've made the reference const), so I make it const here (in the slot side). I've tried to do the same in the signal side with

void dbConnected(QSqlDatabase * const db);

But doing so I have the runtime error (mentioned in [Qt Communication betwen threads, app design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32137149/qt-communication-betwen-threads-app-design)) back. So I tried another form, which seems to do the job:

```
void dbConnected(QSqlDatabase *db) const;
```

Am I in the right direction?

Comment: *I've made the reference const* no, you made the reference refer to a const object. There's no such thing as a "const reference" because references are always const -- you can't reseat them. The logical equivalent of a `const T &r` (reference to const T) is a `const T * const p` (const pointer to const T). What you made is a const pointer to a non-const T; but top-level consts in function signatures are not part of the function signature (they just forbid you from modifying `db` inside the function body). Anyhow: you still need to declare the metatype!

Comment: Ok, got it. May I conclude that, generally, I should prefer to pass the reference and declare the metatype? Or the alternative (don't declare the metatype and pass a pointer) mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32137149/qt-communication-betwen-threads-app-design is acceptle as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I in the right direction?

Maybe. First, make sure that you know that you cannot pass the database to an object living in another thread. That was one of the major mistakes you did in the code in the other question. Don't do that anymore.

If you're passing an object via reference, it must be copyable. A `QSqlDatabase` is copyable *after you open it*. So you're OK here, too.

But you might not need to pass the database reference at all. `QSqlDatabase` assigns a name to each connection. Instead of passing the databases by value or by pointer, you can pass their connection names instead, and use `QSqlDatabase::database` to get a database object representing a given connection.

For example:

```
class Opener : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
  QSqlDatabase m_db;
public:
  Q_SIGNAL void dbOpened(const QString &);
  void open() {
    m_db.addDatabase("FOO", "cats");
    ...
    if (m_db.open()) emit dbOpened(m_db.connectionName());
  }
};

class DbUser : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
  QSqlDatabase m_db;
public:
  Q_SLOT void onDbOpened(const QString & conn) {
    m_db = QSqlDatabase::database(conn);
  }
  ...
};
```

As you can see, the `dbOpened` signal emits not a database, but a database connection name, and then the various objects that wish to use that connection can retrieve the database object (handle) by name.